# How to set a variable containing the year of a field?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

So I have a field CNCL_EFCTV_DT that contains timestamp values i.e. 2022-07-06 06:56:08.656294. What I need to do is set a variable that will return just the year of that timestamp (2022).
I tried using SET year = YEAR(CNCL_EFCTV_DT) but an error pops up saying 'invalid identifier'. How can I fix this??

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
SET year = (SELECT YEAR(CNCL_EFCTV_DT) FROM yourtable WHERE x=y );
```

If more than one record returns:

```
SET year = (SELECT TOP 1 YEAR(CNCL_EFCTV_DT) FROM yourtable WHERE x=y );
```

Comment: Could you please explain me the solution for multiple records? I need to get the year difference for multiple rows but I get the following error: Single-row subquery returns more than one row.

Comment: @AnuarVargas You try to assign the returning value of a query to a variable, but the query returns multiple values. The database can't know which value to assign and gives an error. This is why I put "TOP 1", it will return only the first row. Could you clarify your question? How do you want to assign multiple values to one variable? Something like an array?

Answer (score 0):

The table has to be referenced to get column value:

```
SET year = (SELECT YEAR(NCL_EFCTV_DT) FROM table_name LIMIT 1);

SELECT $year;
```